# Debug pentaho spoon plugin using Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, pentaho-spoon

I am trying to debug a plugin developed in Eclipse for Pentaho spoon / kettle.
if anyone is aware of how to do this i would be pleased to learn. i have googled a lot and found this as most useful reference if someone can make it work.

"https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/6.0/0R0/0V0/010/040"

```
set OPT=%PENTAHO_DI_JAVA_OPTIONS% "-Djava.library.path=%LIBSPATH%" "-DKETTLE_HOME=%KETTLE_HOME%" "-DKETTLE_REPOSITORY=%KETTLE_REPOSITORY%" "-DKETTLE_USER=%KETTLE_USER%" "-DKETTLE_PASSWORD=%KETTLE_PASSWORD%" "-DKETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES=%KETTLE_PLUGIN_PACKAGES%" "-DKETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT=%KETTLE_LOG_SIZE_LIMIT%" "-DKETTLE_JNDI_ROOT=%KETTLE_JNDI_ROOT%"  -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=8044
```

i've implemented OPT variable like this. let me know if any changes are required in here or if there is a whole different way to achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: Can you be a little more clear on what you have achieved till now? And where exactly are you stuck? Essentially, the other URL just speaks of having a typical remote debugging through eclipse, which is practically opening a debug port on host and eclipse connecting to it.

Comment: I want a pentaho plugin to be run directly from development environment. and that is eclipse mars. is there any standard way i can do this. and let me know what more explanation is needed. i can provide all details